# What does symbol [m] means in below equation?

Tags: polynomials

[Please click on this image equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMnoU.png)
Can some one please explain what does [m] means in this equation for Stieltjes Wigert Polynomials.

Comment: It's really hard to know without more context. Could you provide a link, or a greater description?

Comment: This is given in the book "An introduction to orthogonal polynomials" by T S Chihara. I need to calculate these polynomials but since I am not able to understand what does [m] stands for, I am unable do so. This is given on page no 174

Answer (score 0):

Due to my lack of reputation points, I could not post this as a more simple comment.

It appears that m is just a "dummy" variable that is used for the summation. So any letter could be chosen since it does not seem to represent more than a variable used for counting in the sum.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the generalized form of Stieltjes wigert polynomials and its recurring relation?